# How to delete apache axis tmp files without restarting

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

We're using apache axis to talk to a web service. It works fine, but over the course of a day we're generating 1GB of temp files. These files are deleted if we restart the service, but needing to restart the service every day so we don't run out of disk space seems a bit silly.

Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Issue still exists in axis2 1.6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the temp directory path, You may run **rm -rf /path/to/temp/*** every 6 , 12 ..etc through cron.

Or you may write bashscript of you are running on linux system to empty this directory if it reaches a specific size. And put it also in crontab.

Comment: Cheers for the response. I was hoping to avoid this kind of cludge but I'll accept this as it's the only answer I've been given.

Answer (score 5):

We found a programmatic way to avoid generation of those files - which sounds like a better way to do the housekeeping. I posted that [in the comments](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3919?focusedCommentId=13899296&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13899296) of [AXIS2-3919](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3919) issue, but will copy it here just in case:

---

Actually, the files are deployed to the temp folder each time AXIS configuration context is created. Also, it appears that the generated Stub can accept existing configuration object via the constructor. So, the following Spring configuration helped us to solve the issue (irrelevant bean and class names dropped):

```
<bean id="....Stub" factory-bean="...." factory-method="...." scope="request">
    <!-- this next element effects the proxying of the surrounding bean, 
        needed because .... will try to set the stub out of request scope -->
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    <constructor-arg index="0" >
        <!-- The WS stub is created here, and passed to the factory-method of ... as a parameter -->
        <bean class="com......ws.....Stub" scope="prototype">
            <constructor-arg ref="axisConfigContext" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Exists to avoid deployment of axis jar into temp dir for each request. See     AXIS2-3919 for more details. -->
<bean id="axisConfigContext" 
        class="org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory" 
        factory-method="createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem">
    <constructor-arg index="0"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1"><null /></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Nice find, this works perfect for me.  I used a different Spring/Autowire approach but the end result is the same.  No more re-deploying JAR files on every request.

Answer (score 2):

Temp files are created whenever a new ConfigurationContext is created. So create a ConfigurationContext only once in a static block and use it in all the subsequent calls.

```
private static ConfigurationContext configContext;

static {
     configContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, null);
}

public callService() {
    Stub stub = new Stub(configContext, END_POINT_URL);
    //code
}
```

If you don't pass a context, axis2 will create a new context on each call.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution (provided by proudandhonour) of creating static block and it works great. It only creates temp files for the first request. I also update uilimit on Linux server to 16000. Now I don't need to delete temp files.

```
private static ConfigurationContext configContext; 
static{   
   configContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, null);  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your question properly! Mark as code block the part correspondent to your Java code.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at the same problem, and it looks like it might be fixed in version 1.7.0:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3919

I haven't tried it yet, but I'll update this comment once I do.

Answer (score 0):

I counldn't find any other way other then restart every day. Unless you stop the process it will not allow to delete the tmp files. I have changed System Property `"java.io.tmpdir"` to some other location with more disk space, so that atleast it will  not run out of disk space.

```
System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir","/opt/Axis2Temp");
```

Secondly there is another issue related with these files, after runnng app for few hours it will throw Too many open files Exception as below:

> org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-7 org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.[createClassLoader] (856) - Exception extracting jars into temporary directory : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/axis2-tmp-9161756920591296931.tmp/axis21477916618765108874addressing-1.6.0.mar (Too many open files) : switching to alternate class loading mechanism
>
> org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-7 org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.[createClassLoader] (860) - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/axis2-tmp-9161756920591296931.tmp/axis21477916618765108874addressing-1.6.0.mar (Too many open files)

To address this problem I have increased the ulimit for open files to 4000.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this exact problem recently and it is a show stopper for us.  I have a couple of solutions:

1. set the java.io.tmpdir to a directory that does not exist. There may be some undesirable consequences to this!
2. Create a bespoke version of org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils and edit the createClassLoader function. Deploy this in the class path before the axis library. This function takes a boolean extractJars which causes the file to be copied, if that is not possible (e.g. if the tmp dir does not exist) then the class loader will work off the original copy of the jar. Again there may be some undesirable consequences to this. There are a number of variations on this theme, I also looked at adding some code to create just a single copy of the jar but I think this solution is nicer since it uses the existing functionality. Here is my version of the function:

   ```
   public static ClassLoader createClassLoader (URL[] urls,
                                       ClassLoader serviceClassLoader,
                                       boolean extractJars,
                                       File tmpDir,
                                       boolean  isChildFirstClassLoading) {
   List embedded_jars = Utils.findLibJars(urls[0]);
   return createDeploymentClassLoader(urls, serviceClassLoader,
                                  embedded_jars, isChildFirstClassLoading);
   }
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I wish it did, however I cannot guarantee that a jar is before another in the classpath of a Web Application. On the other hand, anyone who has an updated jar with these changes would be a life saver.