# Embedded Jetty on Windows leaving temp files

Tags: embedded-jetty

I have several services implemented using embedded jetty that are causing disk space problems when running in Windows Server. The problem seems to be that the temporary files and folders are not being cleaned up neither when a server thread completes nor when the server process is stopped.

For example, if I run my service using the local user account on Windows, a folder is created in C:\Windows\Temp for each service I have running, with a name pattern of axis-. In those folders are copies of the .jar file for the particular service - one copy for each request that the service has handled.

Since I am not deploying these using a servlet container (no WAR file) I don't have config files to control Jetty's behavior. Is there some other programmatic way to control the cleanup of temp files?

here's an example of my service coding - all of them are the same pattern.

```
Server quoteServer = new Server(ratingServerPort);
    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    PingHandler pingHandler = new PingHandler();
    pingHandler.setLogger(log);
    handlers.addHandler(pingHandler);

    QuoteHandler quoteHandler = new QuoteHandler();
    quoteHandler.setLogger(log);
    quoteHandler.setMongo(mongo);
    quoteHandler.setMorphia(morphia);
    quoteHandler.setMongoHostname(mongoHostname);
    quoteHandler.setMongoPort(mongoPort);
    quoteHandler.setMileageHost(mileageHost);
    quoteHandler.setMileagePort(mileagePort);
    quoteHandler.setTransitURL(transitURL);
    quoteHandler.setAuthKeys(authKeys);
    handlers.addHandler(quoteHandler);

    BangitHandler bangit = new BangitHandler();
    handlers.addHandler(bangit);

    quoteServer.setHandler(handlers);

    try {
        quoteServer.start();
        quoteServer.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only `WebAppContext` based deployments creates temp files within Jetty itself.

(courtesy of the servlet spec and the internal `WebInfConfiguration` class).

If the filename starts with `axis-` it's probably a temporary directory being created by the axis libraries your project likely has.

See past answers on this ([answer 2 by @anton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21735180/775715) and [answer 3 by @code-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42640510/775715) seems more relevant to your specific usecase then the accepted answer) ...

[How to delete apache axis tmp files without restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935581/how-to-delete-apache-axis-tmp-files-without-restarting)